# Is there a Node.js equivalent of JGroups to provide reliable multicast?

Tags: node.js, multicast, jgroups

Does anyone know if there is an equivalent of JGroups for node.js?  I'm looking for something that can provide reliable multicast, and ideally some of the "value add" features of JGroups that are very appealing (e.g. views/cluster membership/management). I'd also like to be able to implement "reliable multicast" over TCP in environments where native multicast is not permitted (e.g. most clouds, e.g. AWS).

I'm interested in this for server-server clustering, messaging, state-sharing and resilience, rather than for multicast to client browsers.

If such a thing does not exist, but you're interested in working with me on an implementation, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

This package lets you build a simple p2p message passing network over TCP; I've never tried it. It seems quite simple compared to JGroups but can be a starting point:

[smokesignal](https://github.com/marcelklehr/smokesignal)